# How to move views dynamically on scroll in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

I am working on assignment where in requirement is to adjust the view width and height dynamically when user scrolls the list.

proposed screen would contain two part

A. linear layout with

1. Image View
2. Text View and
3. button vertically.

B.Scroll view ( Below linear layout)- this would internally contain some child views .

Initially `LinearLayout` should show its members in vertical ( with fixed height and width) order but once user scroll up it should change its members to horizontal with ( height and width is reduced to fix into screen horizontally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass the scrollview and override the onScrollChanged method in it.In onScrollChanged method change the orientation of the top linear layout(i.e. your vertical linear layout)

```
  public class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public MyScrollView(Context context) {
      super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
      super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
      linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    }
  }
```

Or you can do it by adding scroll change listener like below

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {

  @Override
  public void onScrollChanged() {

    int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll view has only one parent child.
After scrollview create one Linear Layout and then implement inside it your code..

Like below code...

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt"/>
</LinearLayout>
```